# In AngularJS, how to initialize a provider with a dynamic value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Very new to AngularJS and looking at the code in this tutorial, http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/eIaGNOAlOk/angularjs-providers.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.provider("game", function () {
  var type;
  return {
    setType: function (value) {
      type = value;
    },
    $get: function () {
      return: {
        title: type + "Craft"
      };
    }
  };
});

app.config(function (gameProvider) {
  gameProvider.setType("War");
});

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, game) {
  $scope.title = game.title;
});
```

So in the app.config we use setType("war") but what if this value is dynamic? When the page loads the value will be provided by the server and set in a HTML data attribute, something like:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl" data-type="space">
  {{ title }}
</div>
```

Is this possible with providers?

Comment: Providers are used to allow service configuration during the *config-phase*. So I don't think those will help you with data rendered directly into the view. If you can't supply those values otherwise, I'd suggest writing a directive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is can be done using another provider method and then calling it inside the config. To make it simple you can also go for the factory method and inject the factory in the config and set the dynamic value

Basic Factory:

```
app.module('getValue', [])
    .factory('fetchValue', function($http) {
        return {
            getType: function(callback) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: "whatever you have"
                }).
                success(function(data) {
                    callback(data);
                }); 
            }
        };

    });
```

And in you app.config you can do like

```
app.config(function (gameProvider,fetchValue) {
  fetchValue.getType(function(data){
      gameProvider.setType(data);
  });  
});
```

Comment: This works, and is a good example, though it won't help if, as described, the required data is rendered into the view by some server-side logic. Also why use callback-injection instead of the returned promise?

Comment: As you say, this is not where I should be trying to set a dynamic variable from the view. Providers are not used for this purpose